# OnCollisionEnter2D called sometimes, but not always

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im trying to remake Pong. I have all my code made, but for some reason the OnCollisionEnter2D doesn't always activate.

Here's the code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{

    if(col.gameObject.name == "paddle")
    {
        float y = hitFactor(gameObject.transform.position, col.transform.position, col.collider.bounds.size.y);


        Vector2 dir = new Vector2(1, y).normalized;


        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = dir * speed;


        Debug.Log(y);

    }
    if (col.gameObject.name == "paddle2")
    {
        float y = hitFactor(gameObject.transform.position, col.transform.position, col.collider.bounds.size.y);
        Vector2 dir = new Vector2(-1, y).normalized;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = dir * speed;
        Debug.Log(y);
    }
```

The code is supposed to create a  Y value based on were the ball hits the paddle so that it can create the direction in which the ball travels, but after monitoring the console i noticed that OnCollisionEnter2D was only activating sometimes, every now and then, without any noticeable pattern.

Any idea why this might be happening? i don't think its cause the object is moving to fast, i turned the speed down to next to nothing and it still wouldn't consistently trigger

Comment: That can be problem with high speed of object that entering collider. Try to check if this problem exists when objects moveing slow.

Comment: You should check for tag instead for name. So you don't have to check for every name but one tag.

Comment: if the speed of your object is the problem (as mentioned in above comments) you might want to use a raycast to detect if you are near a collider

Comment: OnCollisiomEnter2D (and similar functions) have never worked well for me when I need  consistent, accurate collision detection. Not only have I had problems where it is not invoked on fast-moving objects, but I have also encountered instances where it is called multiple times per observable collision. I agree with the comments above about using ray casting. Here is a link to a tutorial: http://deranged-hermit.blogspot.com/2014/01/2d-platformer-collision-detection-with.html?m=1

Comment: OP may also want to look into `Vector3.Reflect()` for his pong bounces.